# Why are CSS styles greyed out in Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, developer-tools

I often use developer tools to test live CSS changes but today I am seeing for the first time that the styles section on a page I'm looking at is greyed out (the background is grey, not the text) and un-editable. I only have the option to revise a specific, singular element's style and not groups of elements.

What causes this to happen?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? I've noticed that sometimes Chrome will "lock" changes I've made using Visual Studio's browser link. It may have to do with that

Answer (score 4):

Every browser has a predefined set of styles used as an initial base point when rendering a web page. These styles are commonly referred to as *User Agent Styles*. In the Chrome Dev tools, these styles are denoted by a gray background.

**SEE IT IN ACTION**

To see this in action press:

1. <kbd>F12</kbd> to open the Chrome Dev tools on this *Stack Overflow* page.
2. Select the <kbd>Elements</kbd> tab in the top of the dev tools.
3. When the HTML markup appears select the `<head>` tag and look to the right hand column.
4. If not already selected, select the <kbd>Styles</kbd> tab in the right hand column.

You should see the following defined styles in that pane:

```
element.style {
}
head {                           user agent stylesheet
    display: none;
}
```

The styles defined for `head` are part of the initial *user agent stylesheet* and denoted by the gray background that you mention above.

Comment: Gotcha- but on the page I'm viewing, elements with custom classes are also un-editable when they normally would be editable.

Comment: @MylesMalloy Hmm, that's odd. I've never seen that before. Do you have a url that you can share so that I can see it live?

Comment: Honestly I'd rather not give that information- but I've noticed that this isn't happening on the "live" version of the site, just the one on the developer server.

Comment: @MylesMalloy No worries. I understand. I think I've seen this happen before with the way Chrome renders frames too? Don't hold me to that though. The vast majority of the time it's user agent styles. It's quite possible, however, that you came across a special circumstance that I'm not aware.

Comment: Yeah its odd, but anyway your help is appreciated.